# removing duplication on random when doing an insert

Tags: loops, random, duplicates, netezza

Good DAy you guys, I am new to sql, netezza, etc...I have been tasked with manipulating actual account numbers for outside company upload of file, I am currently using Netezza, when I create a table and randomize an account number, there are no duplication but when I insert into table after, the random number duplicates(not a lot, but it does) and each random number has to be unique to each distinct account number.

Thank you guys

I am currently trying to use a loop statement but dont know how to build it in

Answer (score 0):

The random function will always return dublicates if you execute it enough times.
Instead, use something like:

```
row_number() over (order by NULL)
```

You probably need to forget about Loops and instead google ‘sql analytic function’

Comment: Thank you, I truly appreciate response, are you able to elaborate with maybe more code possible? Thank you kindly